# How to use AWS AppSync in one account access DynamoDB in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am a beginner of AWS service AppSync and DynamoDB.
I want to ask whether it is possible to use AWS AppSync in one account access DynamoDB in another account?
I follow this tutorial: [AppSync Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html), but when I choose the data source, I don't know how to choose the DynamoDB in my other AWS account.

Could anyone give me some suggestions about the most simple method to implement cross-account access with AppSync and DynamoDB? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd check out [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-lambda-cross-account/) to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think the best way is: replicate a DynamoDB in account A from account B by using DynamoDB Stream and Lambda, and then we can use AppSync in account A to access DynamoDB in account A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is: replicate a DynamoDB in account A from account B by using DynamoDB Stream and Lambda, and then we can use AppSync in account A to access DynamoDB in account A.

Reference:

[Copy DynamoDB table data cross account real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454969/copy-dynamodb-table-data-cross-account-real-time)

https://dzone.com/articles/real-time-cross-region-dynamodb-replication-using